# REST API Java microservice available inside same application server

Tags: java, rest, microservices

I have small Java (Java EE) microservice, that do some calculations. This microservice is running on the same application server as other application, also written in Java EE. First question - should these apps communicate each other by REST API or different way? Second question - if so, is there a way to save some time, by not serializing/deserializing transfer objects? I understand that communication between two apps on different servers (languages) requires serialization/deserialization, but what about mentioned situation?

Comment: That was helpful to me: [Inter-Process Communication in a Microservices Architecture](https://www.nginx.com/blog/building-microservices-inter-process-communication/)

Comment: depends on a lot of things. This is a very basic architecture decision you need to make, based on transaction requirements, synchronous/asynchronous, security, sessions etc. etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> should these apps communicate each other by REST API or different way?

Microservices should communicate over network always. If they have a REST API then use that.

> if so, is there a way to save some time, by not serializing/ deserializing transfer objects?

If they are communicating over network the serialization is a must. Anyway, serialization help the decoupling. Microservices should share data but not schema/classes. The serialization must be done by loosing the schema, i.e. you could use JSON. If you share the schema (classes) you break the microservice's encapsulation. You won't be able to change a microservice implementation with other implementation (that is using a different technology stack, `PHP` with `Nginx` for example).

Answer (score 1):

If efficiency is paramount, you could use [Google's Protobuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/). Its a bit of a pain (when compared to json) but very efficient. Its also language-agnostic (or to be more precise: it has implementations in most common languages).

You basically define a message according to the proto spec and then a special compiler generates the relevant get/set code. you use that in your code to send and receive super-efficient messages.